# Forbidden from deleting managed apps from Intune using MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

While getting managed apps from Intune using the graph api is no problem, every time I try to delete an app from intune, i get 403 forbidden.

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/{appID} - returns 403
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/{appID} - returns 200
```

I've tried adding the application in the app registration portal and adding it as a app in the Azure AD. 
First I get an auth code using from here

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
&redirect_uri=localhost
&client_id={MyAppID}
&resource={ "https://graph.microsoft.com"}
&prompt=admin_consent
&scope=DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All
```

And then obtain a jwt token from here, using the code

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/token
-Body grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirectURI}client_id={App/ClientID}&client_secret={App/ClientSecret}&code={MyAuthCode}&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

I then use the returned token to make calls to the graph api. 
I've also tried using the `common` endpoint, but  to no avail. 
Am i missing some permission scope I need to set? I have the following delegeted perimissions set for the app and im authenticating using an admin account on a MS demo account.

```
Read and write Microsoft Intune apps (preview)
Sign in and read user profile
Read and write directory data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a "Managed" app - those are built-in apps that Intune ships, and can't be deleted.  Can you verify that it works if you create/delete a standard iOS store app via Graph API?

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, i didn't realise that only the apps of type iosStoreApp or androidStoreApp can be deleted.